# How to load wav file into PCM encoded byte array

Tags: go, pcm

I need to load a WAV file into a PCM encoded byte array (`[]byte`).

I found [youpy/go-wav](https://github.com/youpy/go-wav) and [go-audio/wav](https://github.com/go-audio/wav). Both allow me the extract the "samples"
from a wav file. For example in form of the `IntBuffer` type.

But how do these samples relate to the PCM format and howto I convert them to a PCM (linear 16-bit) encoded byte array?

Comment: In what format do you need your byte slice to be in? PCM 8-bit, 16-bit, float?

Comment: The encoding should be linear 16-bit

Comment: The libraries go somewhat too deep for your purpose. You may want to dig into the source (depending on the license).

Comment: If all you want is the content of the file in a byte array you can just read the file using 
ioutil.ReadFile(filename string) ([]byte, error) that way you can skip the audio processing libraries entirely